# What does 'could have' mean

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"Few could have taken advantage of this one-day 'sale' price."
 What does 'could have' mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret this as meaning that not many people **would have had the opportunity or means (been able to)** take advantage of the sale.

---

I have no idea what the context of the sentence is, but the fact that *sale* is in quotation marks, in combination with the earlier part of the sentence, suggests to me (although this is mostly speculation) that it was a sale that few people would have been able to *afford*. For instance, the price of a $50 million dollar mansion being reduced for one day only to $30 million dollars.

The use of the quotation marks strikes me as sarcastic (scare quotes), indicating that most people with a standard amount of money wouldn't have considered even the *sale* price to be anywhere within their normal means.